# How to compare date(only) from SQL Server 2008 database to the system date(only) in console application in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, date

```
lCommon.SetCommandObject("select Card_Id,Date from Student_Attendance where Card_Id='" + CardId + "'AND Date='"+AttenDate+"'");
lReader = lCommon.objCommand.ExecuteReader();
bool flag = lReader.Read();

if (flag != true)
{
   checkAtenDate = lReader["Date"].ToString();
   AttenCardId = lReader["Card_Id"].ToString();
}
```

I have this code where `lcommon` and `lreader` are from my classes. `CardId` and `AttenDate` are variables. Now my requirement is to match `Card_Id` and `Date` from the SQL Server 2008 database, and then on its basis perform a task for that particular value.

I have tried converting the variable value to string and also to `datetime` format. And even tried by changing datatype in database to `date`, `datetime` and also string but unable to match the date value. Kindly help me in doing it. Actually I am trying to match today's date (getting from system) and match it from the database value for per day and perform my task accordingly.

The present problem is the bool value comes true for flag!= true i.e. flag's value is false and the values are not stored in the variables. Do help me.

Comment: a few questions:
1.)the database and the console application are stored on the same machine?
2.)if 1.) is not the case, is the application in the same time zone as the database?

Comment: Remember that DateTime.Now also gives you Time (not only date), so comparing exactly might be difficult.

Comment: Yes Goran, both are on the same machine so on same time zone too.

Comment: yes Snorre, but i have converted both in string format i.e. tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") and also toshortdatestring(). And even in dateformat.

Answer (score 0):

Use [command.Parameters.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and rewrite your SQL:

```
lCommon.SetCommandObject("select Card_Id,Date from Student_Attendance where Card_Id=@Card_Id AND Date=@AttenDate");
```